# How to update Shopware 6 with command line interface?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

How to update Shopware 6 to the newest or latest version using the command line interface?
(yes I know there is a documentation) but is there a concise step by step guide.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you installed Shopware.

When you installed using Zip, you can update using the zip.

- Download it
- Unpack it
- php public/recovery/update/index.php

You can also adjust in the composer.json the `shopware/*` package versions and run `composer update`

If you used once composer, you have to use composer for all next operations, there is no way back to zip updates.

Answer (score 1):

Get update zip file link: https://www.shopware.com/en/changelog/

1. Get zip file to server

```
wget https://www.shopware.com/en/Download/redirect/version/sw6/file/update_v6.4.13.0_a44572dd03739a816771148ad8bf5a0153f6e79a.zip -qq -O /var/www/update6413.zip
```

2. Unzip all files to your Shopware installation

```
unzip -q /var/www/update6413.zip -d /var/www/shopware
```

3. Excute update command

```
php /var/www/shopware/public/recovery/update/index.php
```

Press "ENTER" to start updating

4. Then remove update assets folder

```
rm -r update-assets/
```

and remove update file after update

```
rm update.json
```